# Ubuntu syslog: After log rotation nothing is written on /var/log/syslog

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog

I've been running a Ubuntu VPS for a few weeks now, so a couple of monthly log rotations took place yestarday. For things like `/var/log/wtmp` things look as expected: `logfile` has recent entries, while `logfile.1` older entries. However, `/var/log/syslog` is now empty, even after restarting rsyslog. Any ideas?

I should mention that this is not a duplicate of the similar question [Syslog not logging anything](https://serverfault.com/questions/193071/syslog-not-logging-anything-var-log-syslog-is-empty). As I haven't modified any of the default settings, `/var/log/syslog` *is* included by default in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what might be happening, but I've got a few questions that could help to debug it:

- Is rsyslogd running? (obvious, but just in case ...)
- If you execute the command "logger test", does anything appear in /var/log/syslog?
- Does /dev/log exist, with permissions for everyone to read and write? Is it a socket? ("file /dev/log")
- What happens in you stop rsyslogd and then run it with "-d"? Does it output any error? Does it output a start message to /var/log/syslog?
- Does anything change if you move the contents of /etc/rsyslog.d out of the way, and restart rsyslog just with the basic configuration?

Hope this helps.

Comment: First time problem was with owner on `/var/log/syslog` being `root:root`. But then I have changed to `syslog:adm` and logs started writting after restarting service, but still after logrotate logs are not written. Thank your for second suggest `logger test`, I will test it on next stuck. `rsyslogd -d | grep error` doesn't show any errors. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: Boom! A bad config file inside `/etc/rsyslog.d` was today's culprit.